# Talking about Front End Web Development frameworks from a designer's perspective

Tags: web-development, graphics

I am a Web Developer working at a company where the fronted framework we have selected is Angular JS. I am now in the position where I am the 'resident expert' whatever that may mean. I have been tasked with teaching/explaining everything that our Designers need to know about Angular JS. Unfortunately my knowledge/understanding of design begins and ends with the color wheel. Therefore I have the following question:

What, if anything would a designer need to know about a front end javascript framework in general/Angular JS in particular in order to streamline their productivity? What kind of things are irrelevant? What kind of things are important?

Comment: I expect they would mostly want to know about any restrictions that using AngularJS puts on their designs, but why not ask them: they tend to hang out on [ux.se]. (Oh, please don't cross post your question, if you want it moved to ux, just [flag] this question for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated.

Comment: Maybe useful : hackdesign.org

Comment: If you need vanilla crap done fast, you're all good. If you need something specific, you're likely SOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was working with Android, here is what our designer wanted to know:

1. what is possible (compared to other technologies)
2. what is impossible (compared to other technologies)
3. what is generally accepted and "traditional"
4. what is more convenient (in our specific case it was button sizes or different keypads for different cases)
5. most recent samples with exceptional quality of UI (you or the designer need to follow the market and get new applications not to miss the latest tendencies)
6. resolution issues (though I doubt you will need this with JS framework)
7. any specific requirements for the resources, like images, icons, etc.

After all these points were covered, the cases when the designer asked for something impossible or needed any additional information were very rare.